# Onload function to call an action to achieve "Save and Print" through javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, pdf

I have a invoice form in which i want to add option to print invoice on form submit. for this i have added a button and made some changes in controller.Here is my code

In invoice form:

```
<%= form_for @invoice do |f| %>
   :
   **Invoice fields**
   :

 <%= f.submit "Save", :name=>"save", :class=>'btn btn-success' %>
 <%= f.submit "Save & Print", :name=>"save_and_print", :class=>'btn btn-default' %>
<% end %>
```

And in my controller i did this:

```
def create
     :
     :
      if params[:save_and_print]
       format.html { redirect_to("/invoices/#{@invoice.id}?save_and_print=1", :notice => 'Invoice  has been saved and printed.') }
       else
        format.html { redirect_to(@invoice, :notice => 'Invoice has been saved.') }
       end
    end

    def show
     :
     :
      respond_to do |format|
       format.pdf do 
        template=Invoice.get_template(@company, "Invoice", params[:dlc])
        pdf=InvoicePdf.new(@invoice, view_context, @receipt_vouchers)
        send_data pdf.render, :filename=>"#{@invoice.invoice_number}.pdf",  :disposition=>"inline", :type=>'pdf'
      end
      end 
    end
```

And here is my link to print pdf:

```
<%= link_to raw('<i class="icon-print"> </i>'), invoice_path(@invoice, :format => 'pdf'), :target=>"_blank", :title=>"Print" %>
```

I am thinking to create an onload function to trigger generate pdf link on view page load after form submit. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try replacing this line `if !params[:save_and_print].blank? && params[:save_and_print]=="1"` with `if params[:submit] == "save_and_print"`.

Comment: @Pavan logically this should not work because in show screen i think params submit will not received. Thanks for such a quick answer i will try this.

Comment: Hi @Pavan i am thinking to do this through javascript. On view screen load will trigger a function to call pdf generation action.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it is not redirecting to invoice view screen is because of this line `if params[:save_and_print]`,it should be `if params[:submit] == "save_and_print"`

```
if params[:submit] == "save_and_print" #here
  format.html { redirect_to("/invoices/#{@invoice.id}?save_and_print=1", :notice => 'Invoice  has been saved and printed.') }
else
  format.html { redirect_to(@invoice, :notice => 'Invoice has been saved.') }
end
```

You should be accessing the value passed to the **`submit button`** through giving **`params[:submit]`**.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply @Pavan but this change will only redirect user on view screen and will not generate the PDF. I want to generate PDF and redirect to view screen both on form submit.

Comment: @Ravindra How you are generating the PDF,can u post that code?

Answer (score 0):

I have got a simple solution for my problem. First of all i gave id to  my print pdf link and than call that link on page load. Here is my solution :

```
<%= link_to raw('<i class="icon-print"> </i>'), invoice_path(@invoice, :format => 'pdf', :dlc=>"no"), :class => 'btn btn-white btn-lg', :id=>"print1-inv", :target=>"_blank", :title=>"Print" %>
```

and script on show.html.erb:

```
<% if !params[:save_and_print].blank? && params[:save_and_print]=="1" %>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#print1-inv")[0].click();
  });
</script>
<% end %>
```

this code works for me.